# How to have all lower case keys in a Key-Value pair - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Brand new to Scala, sorry for the easy question. I need to produce map reduce logic in Scala that creates key-value pairs from words in a text file. The words are the keys and the count of the words are the values.

My issue: *I need all keys to be lower case*

My current code:

```
val test = sc.textFile("cat.txt");
val flattenMap = test.flatMap(line => line.split(" "));
val mapreduce = flattenMap.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b);
```

My keys are mixed case and I would like them to be all lower case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the following statement on line 3:

```
val mapreduce = flattenMap.map(word => (word.toLowerCase, 1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b);
```